# Error Flutter Image Slider line 822 pos 12: 'elapsedInSeconds >= 0.0': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, carousel, flutter-animation

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in flutter ? animation_controler.dart

```
"_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 822 pos 12: 'elapsedInSeconds >= 0.0': is not true.)"

@pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? messages);
```

When I run the image slider, it always gets an error like that for a while and it's very annoying. thank you very much for helping answer

Comment: Can you include your widget

Comment: After each flutter update, I just comment out the line with the assert, in flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart line 822

Answer (score -1):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Image Slider'),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: 200,
    child: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: true,
        ),
        items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((e) {
          return Builder(builder: ((context) {
            return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Images $e'),
              ),
            );
          }));
        }).toList()),
  )),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).